Why isn't "Shade Smooth" in Blender 4.2 working on my 96 vert cones and other shapes?
Bender 4.2 user. Recently there is an issue with some shapes not smoothing when told, such as the prementioned Cone. Using "Shade Smooth" by angle or not, doesn't smooth out my geo (with or without "Keep Sharp"). When I orbit the geo, I see stepping on it's surface; I use mats and HDRIs, nothing seems to smooth this issue. [Pictured is a cone 96 vert base and the settings I have for the attached mods (Bevel and Weighted Normal).] (https://i.sstatic.net/wifuhkLY.png)
I have tried using different mods (Auto Smooth, Weighted Normals, Shade Smooth, Smooth, Bevel, ect...) in different orders to see if that would help and nothing really helps other than blowing up the vert numbers.
